# Magento 1.9 - Totally email not working in my store

Tags: magento-1.9, email, cron

another critical problem when going to send email from my store.can't send any email through the store site.Also i checked core_email_queue table & email-queue _recipient ,no records there. I'm using magento 1.9.4.3. How email settings should be?

[image]

Here is email template have change code as below.
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Here is my cron -  * * * * * sh /var/www/m2/cron.sh
can anybody help me to resolev this please.
Thank you.

Comment: er... it's not wise to put credentials in your code O.o

Comment: OMG... thank you jscar